# Get method's attribute without creating instance

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class Person
{
   [SomeCustomAttribute]
   public void blahblahblah()
   {}
}
```

Is it possible to extract the attributes of a method by reflection, without creating the instance? I know it's not possible for instance property, how about instance method? Will it work if the method is static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
public class Person
{
    [Obsolete("Obsolete field")]
    public int Field { get; set; }

    [Obsolete("Obsolete property")]
    public int Property { get; set; }

    [Obsolete("Obsolete method")]
    public void blahblahblah()
    { }
}
```

Then

```
Type type = typeof(Person);

foreach (var field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
{
    foreach (var attr in field.GetCustomAttributes(false))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Field {0}: attribute {1}", field, attr);
    }
}

foreach (var property in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
{
    foreach (var attr in property.GetCustomAttributes(false))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Property {0}: attribute {1}", property, attr);
    }
}

foreach (var method in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
{
    foreach (var attr in method.GetCustomAttributes(false))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method {0}: attribute {1}", method, attr);
    }
}
```

Reflection for "analyzing" types requires only the `Type` object, not an instance of the clas you want to analyze. And attributes "live" in the `Type`, not in each instance of the object. If `Type` is known at compile time (`typeof(Person)`) then there is no problem here. The same if it is the `T` of a generic `MyMethod<T>()`. The third common method is if you have a `myObj` instance, then `myObj.GetType()` will return the `Type` of the instance. There is a fourth method using a `string` and using `Type.GetType()` but it requires the full name, so it is complex.

You can "analyze" (enumerate) with reflection fields, properties, methods (their descriptor, not their value. The metadata to be clear!)... All starting with the `Type` object. What you can't do without an instance of the object is get the value of instance fields/properties, set the value of instance fields/properties, invoke instance methods (but clearly you can do all of the above with `static` fields/properties/methods)

Answer (score 2):

You make the class static (actually, the static class has an instance behind the scenes).

Inside that static class (or from any external class) you may do what ever you want without instantiating an object (including getting the attribute).